# Not able to install JQ in mac using homebrew

Tags: linux, macos, ansible, homebrew

I am trying to install JQ on mac using this Playbook.
Homebrew has been installed in the target machine manually.

```yaml
- name: install jq using homebrew
  homebrew:
    name: jq
    state: present
```

when I run this, I am facing below error

> fatal: [X.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find required executable brew in paths: /Users/xxxx/Documents/ansible/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin"}

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You normally need `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH to use `brew` or anything it installs.

Comment: @MarkSetchell so you mean to tell need to have /usr/local/bin path in target machine??? can you please suggest me to resolve this? As of now used macports to install jq, but would like to know about homebrew also

Comment: I don't know anything about *"Playbooks"*. All I am saying is that if you want to run `brew install jq` you will likely need your PATH to contain `/usr/local/bin` And if you subsequently want to use `jq`, you will also need it in your PATH. So `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am less familiar with using Ansible playbooks for installing brew formulae, but based on the provided `PATH`, I think you did miss `/usr/local/bin` (as Mark commented).

Reading [this Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/homebrew_module.html), did you install the homebrew module as well? If you have brew present in a different PATH, you can certainly modify your syntax as

```
# Install formula foo with 'brew' in alternate path C(/my/other/location/bin)
- name: install jq using homebrew
  homebrew:
    name: jq
    path: /my/other/location/bin
    state: present
```